# moving from Glut to SDL2

Tags: glut, sdl2

I'm using Glut with OpenGL for drawing. Glut is very simple and straightforward but I have to give up Glut and move on toward SDL2. I'm reading SDL for Game Development, good book. I need to speed up a bit, so I'm looking for a list of comparisons between Glut and SDL2. At least with common similarities between the two. For example, in Glut we need for drawing `Display()` to be passed to `glutDisplayFunc()`. My understanding so far for SDL2 is that `SDL_Renderer` is like `Display()` in Glut. Is this correct? Also, what do exactly `SDL_Surface` and `SDL_RenderPresent` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the same transition recently. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is "SDL Best Practices" but it does work. It doesn't use and SDL_Renderer or SDL_Surface...

Here's a segment of my code. Much of it is pasted from forgotten internet pages. I *think* I left in everything relevant, after snipping out some of my app-specific goop. I hope it helps. (And feedback from anyone who knows better is definitely welcome here!)

As for the actual question, a comparison of glut to sdl, for me it was just:

GLUT:

- install callbacks for events like draw, keyboard mouse
- 1 special window by default

SDL2:

- your own main event loop, and switch on event type yourself
- explicit window creation & control

Example code:

```
SDL_Window *mainwindow; /* Our window handle */
SDL_GLContext maincontext; /* Our opengl context handle */

if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) /* Initialize SDL's Video subsystem */
    sdldie("Unable to initialize SDL"); /* Or die on error */

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

// next line as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961116/opengl-3-x-context-creation-using-sdl2-on-osx-macbook-air-2012
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

/* Turn on double buffering with a 24bit Z buffer.
 * You may need to change this to 16 or 32 for your system */
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 32);

/* Create our window centered */
mainwindow = SDL_CreateWindow("The Window Name", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              1600, 800, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

maincontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainwindow);

/* This makes our buffer swap syncronized with the monitor's vertical refresh */
SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

/* Clear our buffer with a red background */
glClearColor ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

/* Swap our back buffer to the front */
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainwindow);

SDL_Delay(200);

while (!quit)
{
  draw(); // does glDrawXxx stuff here.
  SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainwindow);

  while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
    switch(e.type)
    {
      case SDL_QUIT:
        quit = true;
        break;

        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
         /* et cetera */
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007329/what-is-a-sdl-renderer which describes the various SDL types. It seems like you'd use these as an alternative to OpenGL for some kinds of window contents.